replacing file content by a powershell pipeline in DevOps
I want to use a powershell pipeline to change a file content from DevOps.
My file content is as follows:

For example, I want to change Initial Catalog=databricks_connection to Initial Catalog=new_value.
This is the powershell script that I created:
param (
[string]$filePath,
[string]$searchString,
[string]$replaceString
)


$fileContent = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw


$newContent = $fileContent -replace [regex]::Escape($searchString), 
$replaceString


$newContent | Set-Content -Path $filePath

Write-Host "Content replaced successfully in file: $filePath"

This is my YML pipeline:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Replace File Content'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/powershell.ps1'
    arguments: '-filePath $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/databricks_report.Report/definition.pbir -searchString "Initial Catalog=databricks_connection" -replaceString "Initial Catalog=new_value"'

Whenever I run the pipeline, it didn't throw any errors and the pipeline is completed every time. However, the target file doesn't get any updates at all. Is there any missing part from my script?
How can I update my file content by the pipeline I called?
